# How to debug a UWP application on Microsoft HoloLens?

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens

Microsoft provides a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-plugin) for writing your own device portal plugin. When I deploy my plugin/UWP application via the HoloLens device portal (View > Apps) to the HoloLens and try to run it I receive a message "Failed to start package !App (0x80070005)".

I've tried to debug the application as described in the tutorial (and as described in the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-visual-studio)). I've set a breakpoint in the "Run" method and in a callback which is triggered when a [request to the device portal is received](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.diagnostics.deviceportal.deviceportalconnection.requestreceived?view=winrt-18362).

When I hit debug button in VS the app is deployed and the debugger seems to run (can't start another debug session or else (buttons are greyed out) but I don't see any locals, call stack, etc. When I hit the pause button I get an "Unable to break execution. No processes are currently being debugged". What am I missing?

Comment: Since you receive a message "Failed to start package! App (0x80070005)", we think that the application is not even starting to point to get to the breakpoint in question, and it won’t debug until the application actually starts and runs. Besides, which device are you using? HL1 or HL2? Did you hit the breakpoint in OnLauched() in the debugger?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've tried to deploy the device portal plugin to the device portal on my windows machine but had no luck in debugging it. I'm pretty new to windows development and uwp in particular, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something? The plugin is only active when a corresponding service request is made. Correct? So, something like http://localhost:50080/MyNamespace/api/echo - also I'm using HL1